Verifying if a function is surjective
Today I had a discussion with my teacher (I'm in high school). She said that you can verify if a function $f$ is surjective by finding its inverse $f^{-1}$ and verifying that its domain equals the codomain of $f$.
I think that this is circular reasoning, since you can't assert the existence of $f^{-1}$ without already assuming that $f$ is surjective. She argued that, for example, if you have the function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by the equation $y=x^2$, you can solve for $x$ and you'll have that $x=\pm\sqrt y$; knowing that the domain of $y\mapsto\sqrt y$ is $\mathbb R_{\ge0}$, you can say that $f$ is not surjective.
I think that doesn't work either. Yes, you can avoid the problem of the existence of $f^{-1}$ considering the inverse relation (not requiring for it to be a function) and checking its domain, but still I see a problem, even if $f$ were invertible: you have no information about $f^{-1}$ except the fact that it's the inverse function of $f$, so how would you know its domain without already knowing the image of $f$?
She said it's given that the domain of $x\mapsto\sqrt x$ is $\mathbb R_{\ge0}$, and that you don't have to prove it every time. Of course I agree with that, but still you can't use this "given" fact to prove that the image of $x\mapsto x^2$ is $\mathbb R_{\ge0}$, because if you actually wanted to prove it you'd need to know the latter. I'm not saying I'm right, I'm asking for a clarification.
Thanks in advance.

Surjective functions need not possess simply defined inverses, but if you can write down an inverse function that is defined on the entire codomain, then of course the function is surjective.  I agree that the "argument" you give for $x^2$ is circular.  It's fine to quote old results, of course, but quoting a result isn't the same as providing a proof.

@lulu yeah, but if you assume that the inverse function exists you're implicitly assuming that the original function is surjective.

You can not prove the existence of an inverse merely by assuming that it exists.  As you surmise, that is circular.

@Kan't you can see $y=x^2$ as a relation though, and thus you can consider the domain of its inverse relation, I think. Not sure tho.

She probably meant: ${\rm im}(f)={\rm dom}(f^{-1})={\rm dom}(y\mapsto\pm\sqrt y)={\rm dom}(\sqrt~)=\Bbb R_{\ge0}$

I like to think about this in terms of left and right inverses:
Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map, $g:Y\to X$  is called a left-inverse of $f$ if $$g\circ f=id_X.$$
In a similar fashion $h:Y\to X$ is called a right-inverse of $f$ if $$f\circ h=id_Y.$$
It then can be shown that $f$ has a left-inverse if and only if it is injective and has a right-inverse if and only if it is surjective.
This means that if you want to know whether $f$ is surjective you can try to find a right-inverse of it (which is basically how everyone proves surjectivity anyways). If you cannot find one, then you either try to prove that it isn't surjective or give up I guess.
For example, $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ with $f(x)=x^2$ is surjective since $h:\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $h(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is its right-inverse. Obviously, you need to make an argument for the existence of square-roots of positive real numbers in some way. That is kinda hard tho.
About the existence of square-roots of positive real numbers $a$:
It relies on the fact that in $\mathbb{R}$ every convergent sequence of real numbers has a limit which lies in $\mathbb{R}$ itself. Assuming that, one can show that the sequence $$x_n:=x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}}$$ where $x_0\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is arbitrary converges to a positive solution of $x^2-a$.

Well, you are indeed correct and it is circular reasoning. Your teacher's misunderstanding possibly stems from the fact that most proofs of proving surjectivity in school go like this:

We are given $f(x)$.
Set $y=f(x)$ and solve for $x$ in terms of $y$.
Claim that it is surjective if the expression of $x$ is "always" valid.

However, of course, that is not correct and the right thing to do is pretty much the same, except if you do get surjectivity, say that here is the preimage for any given $y$, and if you don't, find something that is not attainable by that expression and claim that there is no such $x$.
(Also, you are absolutely correct about the $x\mapsto x^2$ example.)
Hope this helps. :)
